# c++ Qt DBus no such signal InterfacesAdded

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to connect to the InterfacesAdded signal from the ObjectManager using the following code:

```
UDisks::UDisks(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent), disks(UD_SERVICE,
    UD_PATH, UD_INTERFACE_OBJECT_MANAGER, QDBusConnection::systemBus())
{
    qDBusRegisterMetaType<InterfaceList>();
    qDBusRegisterMetaType<ManagedObjectList>();

    connect(&disks, SIGNAL(InterfacesRemoved(QDBusObjectPath, QStringList)), this, SLOT(mediaRemoved(QDBusObjectPath, QStringList)));
    connect(&disks, SIGNAL(InterfacesAdded(QDBusObjectPath, InterfaceList)), this, SLOT(mediaAdded(QDBusObjectPath,InterfaceList)));

}
```

When I run the code, It comes up with the following error:

```
QObject::connect: No such signal org::freedesktop::DBus::ObjectManager::InterfacesAdded(QDBusObjectPath, InterfaceList)
```

Here is the typedef for the InterfaceList:

```
typedef QMap<QString, QMap<QString, QVariant>> InterfaceList;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By debugging the QtDBusViewer I was able to find the solution to my problem by using this code:

```
QDBusConnection connection(QDBusConnection::systemBus());
connection.connect(UD_SERVICE, UD_PATH, UD_INTERFACE_OBJECT_MANAGER, "InterfacesAdded", this, SLOT(mediaAdded(QDBusObjectPath,InterfaceList)));
```

It turned out I needed to create a connection to the signal using the QDbusConnection class rather than using the QObject's connect method.